# Creating a string from my matched elements

Tags: jquery

I currently create two strings using the following code. One is for a load of HTML content and the other is a string of post IDs.

What I cant seem to do is to get the string of post IDs as a comma-separated string. I figured it has something to do with `.join()`, I just don't know how to fit it in.

```
var content = '';
var postidstring = '';

jQuery('.apartment-entry-container:has(input:checked)').each(function() {
   content += jQuery(this).html();  
   postidstring += jQuery(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').val();                        
   //console.log(postidstring);                    
});
```

The console reads 00010002000300040005 instead of 0001,0002,0003,0004,0005 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Make `postidstring` an array. Push stuff into it. At the end, perform a `join()` with `","` as the delimiter:

```
var content = '';
var postidstring = [];

jQuery('.apartment-entry-container:has(input:checked)').each(function() {
  content += jQuery(this).html();  
  postidstring.push(jQuery(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').val());                        
}); 

console.log( postidstring.join(',') );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do,

```
var content = '';
var postidstring = '';

jQuery('.apartment-entry-container:has(input:checked)').each(function() {
   content += jQuery(this).html();  
   var str = jQuery(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').val();
   postidstring += postidstring.length > 0 ? ',' + str : str;                     
   //console.log(postidstring);                    
});
```